# How to JOIN more than one table from different databases?

Tags: sql, database

How to write a `SELECT` query that selects values from different tables and different databases?

e.g

```
dbSALES
       tbSalesOrder

dbSHIPMENT
       tbShipmentDetails and tbShipmentMaster.
```

My main aim is to JOIN all the tables

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will generally work:

```
SELECT ...
FROM dbSALES.tbSalesOrder
JOIN dbSHIPMENT.tbShipmentDetails ON ...
JOIN dbSHIPMENT.tbShipmentMaster ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SQL Server.

It will be written using a normal `SELECT` with `JOIN`, but use a fully qualified tables' names like `database.schema.object_name`. Like this:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM dbSALES.tbSalesOrder
INNER JOIN dbSHIPMENT.tbShipmentDetails ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use something along these lines:

```
SELECT [column-list]
FROM
    dbSales.[schema].tbSalesOrder SO
    JOIN dbSHIPMENT.[schema].tblShipmentDetails SD ON SD.[join_column] = SO.[join_column]
    JOIN dbSHIPMENT.[schema].tbShipmentMaster SM ON SM.[join_column] = SD.[join column]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from dbSales.tbSalesOrder a
         join dbShipment.tbShipmentDetails b on (a.field1=b.field1 and ......)
         join dbShipment.tbShipmentMaster c on (b.field1=c.field1 and ......)
where a.field1=xxxx and b.field2=yyyy
```